# Delete particular log from call log

Tags: android, calllog

I want to delete a particular entry from call log only once..

```
getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(calluri, queryString, null);
```

The above code delete all the entries from call log

Comment: try do delete call log by call id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try do delete call log by call id. use below code

```
int res = Call_logs.this.getContentResolver().delete(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,"_ID = "+ calls_id_list.get(i),null);
        if (res == 1) {
            // Log delete

        } else {
            // Log not Delete

        }
```

to delete all call log:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");

int d  = getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks and to get call list we can use

String[] strFields = { android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, android.provider.CallLog.Calls._ID, android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE,
   android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE };
     String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";

     Cursor mCallCursor = mainCntx.getContentResolver().query(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, strFields, null, null, strOrder);

Answer (score 0):

**STEP 1:**
Make sure that you have following permission in manifast.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

**STEP 2:**
And for deleting Call logs for particular number:

```
public void deleteCallLogByPhoneNumber(String number) {   

    String queryString="NUMBER="+number; 
    this.getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,queryString,null);

}
```